# Problem with installation and first login

Tags: boot, login-screen

I tried to install the Ubuntu but had notice a problem twice and it will allow to get in to the desktop, but it appears the login to write a username and a password. I tried ignore it, put space, create a name, how can I login at first time? It happens because there was a problem during the installation?  And how can I identify and solve this problem? I followed all the steps, burned a DVD with the Ubuntu system, boot the computer with the DVD, until the step to choose install or try (I chose install).

Comment: You said you can get to a desktop. Are you talking about the desktop *while you're installing*, or afterwards? If it's afterwards, are you saying that you can boot into a working, usable Ubuntu system (without the install DVD in the computer)? If so, does the login screen (or whatever else is asking for your username and password) appear *before* you get a working desktop, or does it appear at some point *after*? If after, this could be the screen locking automatically, and asking for your password to unlock it, but it wouldn't ask for your username. If before, are you logging in as guest?

Comment: The password for most things in Ubuntu is the one you set during installation, so if you don't remember setting one (or if you set a blank password and you're unable to authenticate successfully with it), then you should be able to solve the problem by [resetting the password to something that is not blank](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). However, we won't really be able to answer your question definitively until you explain what's going on in more detail. Please edit your question to provide the information I've requested.

Answer (score 0):

A username cannot contain white spaces and it must be a single word. A name can be your name [space] surname.

It is usually recommended to only use usernames that begin with a lower case letter or an underscore, followed by lower case letters, digits, underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar sign.In regular expression terms: [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]? On Debian, the only constraints are that usernames must neither start with a dash ('-') nor contain a colon (':') or a whitespace (space: ' ', end of line: '\n', tabulation: '\t', etc.). Note that using a slash ('/') may break the default algorithm for the definition of the user's home directory. Usernames may only be up to 32 characters long

Comment: Are you thinking that this is happening *during* the installation, when the user sets their username and password, rather than *after* installation? The question is vague but may be consistent with this interpretation. Can you expand this to explain the difference between *username* and *name* in greater detail? (Also, are there other characters besides whitespace characters, that cannot be present in a username? You may want to mention that it cannot *start* with a number...)

Comment: It is usually recommended to only use usernames that begin with a lower case letter or an underscore, followed by lower case letters, digits, underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar sign.In regular expression terms: [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?

On Debian, the only constraints are that usernames must neither start with a dash ('-') nor contain a colon (':') or a whitespace (space: ' ', end of line: '\n', tabulation: '\t', etc.).

Note that using a slash ('/') may break the default algorithm for the definition of the user's home directory.

Usernames may only be up to 32 characters long.

Comment: Yes, what I'm suggesting is that you add some of this information to your answer.